# iPhone Sub Tabs - Navigation

Tags: iphone, design-patterns, user-interface, tabs

I'm in the process of designing UI for an iPhone app, and we are going to have a standard 4 tab bar across the bottom. We are considering using that same tab bar in a contextual way, so that when you tap a search result the options across the bottom will change to be contextual to the item pressed.

Does this way of doing things represent a huge usability issue, or is it Okay to-do if we are consistent about the execution?

screen1 tab navigation across bottom: A B C D:

-a search result is clicked

-new page is focused with detail view of result

screen2 tab navigation across bottom: E F G H:

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that on the same tabBar, you can hide the tabBar and present another tabBar with the desired items, you can hide/show the tabBar using this methods:

```
- (void)hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        } 
        else 
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
        }
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];   
}

- (void)showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{       
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", view);

        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];

        } 
        else 
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 431)];
        }
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
```

You can use these methods like this:

```
[self hideTabBar:self.tabBarController];
[self showTabBar:self.tabBarController];
```

When hiding the tabBar, initiate a new one with and add it to the view.